# Using MS who bot outside Teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Can we expose Microsoft new Who bot outside MS teams? Can I use it on my Website? I am already researched on the internet and it seems we have very less information on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible, I'm afraid, and we have no current plans to support this scenario.